# How to create subblock inside block with Rebol

Tags: rebol

I want to get

```
[["1" "a"] ["2" "b"]]
```

from

```
["1" "" "a" "2" "" "b"]
```

What's the right and most elegant way? I tried this but it doesn't get the result I want:

```
block: ["1" "" "a" "2" "" "b"]

new-block: []
sub-block: []

foreach [first second third] block [
  sub-block: []
  append sub-block first
  append sub-block third
  append new-block sub-block
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach [a b c] block [repend/only [] [a c]]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
newblock: copy [] forskip block 3 [repend/only newblock [block/1 block/3 ]]
== [["1" "a"] ["2" "b"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to use `COLLECT/KEEP`:

```
collect [
    foreach [first second third] block [
        keep/only collect [
            keep first
            keep third
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: +1 for COLLECT.   Here's another variation: `collect [foreach [first second third] block [keep/only reduce [first third]]]`

Comment: @draegtun I figured I'd go all-in with COLLECT for this example :)

Answer (score 1):

Another, less elegant approach is:

```
>> parse ["1" "" "a" "2" "" "b"] [
         2 [set a string! skip set b string!
            (append x: [] reduce [a b])
         ]
   ]
>> x
== ["1" "a" "2" "b"]
```

Answer (score 1):

For more variety here's a solution using [`MAP-EACH`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/map-each.html)

```lisp
map-each [first second third] block [reduce [first third]]
```

NB. Above works in Rebol (2 & 3).  `MAP-EACH` currently not available in Red.